Finding any spanning tree that covers a subgraph of a directed graph
My work (programmer) has a business use case that basically boils down to the following graph theory problem:
Given a directed graph $F$ and a subset of vertices / subgraph $G = v_1, v_2, ... , v_k$ we want to find any spanning tree and its root.
Does this fit into a well-studied problem archetype?
Does lifting the restriction from a minimum spanning tree to any spanning tree make this more tractable?
Time complexity isn't too important, but I'm hoping to find a less-than-exponential-time algorithm...

If you're working with directed graphs you probably want to look at spanning arborescences, not trees. Edmonds' algorithm might be relevant.

I came across Edmond's algorithm, but I don't think it supports picking some vertices from the graph and generating the spanning tree across that subgraph, right?

Which relation do you expect between spanning arborescence and subset of vertices? Are you talking about directed version of Steiner tree problem?
